# The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.4,15.0.4], [16.0.0,16.0.0]]

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, google-play-services

Can anyone help me with running this project?`https://github.com/x3388638/LANChat`, I encounter lots of tasks and can't fix it, I thought the problem is the old version. What am I supposed to do?                                          I've tried add some dependencies and change variety version of gradle `com.android.tools.build:gradle`
But I can't post the change I made due to it seems like a spam...
Currently problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk4YF.png)